# Using meteor collection hook after insert

Tags: meteor

I want to write into another collection after insert and for that task,i am using meteor collection hooks package https://github.com/matb33/meteor-collection-hooks

I am wondering how i would fire the callback after insert. Currenty i am using this code to insert

```
 'schoolNew': function(post){

      Schools.insert({
          schoolname: post.input_sn,
          schooldescription: post.input_sd,
          schoollocation: post.input_sl,
          schoollogo: post.input_ls
      });
},
```

As the doc says https://github.com/matb33/meteor-collection-hooks#afterinsertuserid-doc

> Fired after the doc was inserted.

How exactly do i use the callback?.

Comment: after insert return that id and you can fetch the data with that id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just define the collection hook like so for example:

```
Schools.after.insert(function(userId, doc) {
   console.log(this);
   console.log(userId, doc);
});
```

and it will be called automatically after every(!!!) insert into the `Schools` collection.

Comment: Sounds magical,but it messes with every other package i have https://github.com/vsivsi/meteor-job-collection/issues/58#issuecomment-72272402

Comment: i know that sucks! try this: `Mongo.Collection.prototype.constructor = Mongo.Collection` before defining the `new JobCollection`.

Answer (score 0):

I added the hook like this

```
  'schoolNew': function(post){

      Schools.insert({
          schoolname: post.input_sn,
          schooldescription: post.input_sd,
          schoollocation: post.input_sl,
          schoollogo: post.input_ls
      });
      Schools.after.insert(function (userId, doc) {
      var newid = this._id;
      console.log(newid);
     });
},
```

I did run into issues though but this comment will help you https://github.com/vsivsi/meteor-job-collection/issues/58#issuecomment-72272402

Comment: the `Schools.after.insert` does not go into the `method`.